# Does this error message, "There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing" point me to the source of the error? If so, how?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I get these two errors frequently while starting my React project:

```
./node_modules/process/browser.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postMassiv\frontend\node_modules\process\browser.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postMassiv\frontend\node_modules\axios\lib\defaults.js
* C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\process\browser.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\react-error-overlay\lib\index.js

./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postMassiv\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 5 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postMassiv\frontend\node_modules\mini-create-react-context\dist\esm\index.js
* C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Roland\2020-Coding-Projects\postmassiv\frontend\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
```

I want to eliminate them.

In other threads people cite fixing things like `"import React from 'React'" --> "import React from 'react'"` to be in line with their other imports (note the lowercase R)

My question is, does this error message somehow tell me where to look or what to do to make the message go away? If it's apparent from the error message, I do not understand where the information is conveyed. The warnings just look like "blah blah blah" to me.

If it's the case that *any* of my project's import statements could be the cause, and it's *not* pointing me to the source of the error... Well I have 196 imports in my React project so I'm not happy if I have to manually compare each one... Suggestions? I looked thru other threads (a dozen) and none gave instructions for tracking down the source of the error.

So far I've found a handful of imports where I had, say, `import Fave from "../../images/twit_fave.png";` and `import FaveImg from "../../images/twit_fave.png";` (note "Fave" and "FaveImg"), or a `.scss` extension inconsistently present at the end of a SCSS file import. But the warning has not gone away.

TL:DR; Please explain how this error message presents the clues required to make it go away. If they're there, I do not see them.

edit2: To see how `global.js` is unlikely to be responsible, here is its contents:

```js
var g;

// This works in non-strict mode
g = (function() {
    return this;
})();

try {
    // This works if eval is allowed (see CSP)
    g = g || new Function("return this")();
} catch (e) {
    // This works if the window reference is available
    if (typeof window === "object") g = window;
}

// g can still be undefined, but nothing to do about it...
// We return undefined, instead of nothing here, so it's
// easier to handle this case. if(!global) { ...}

module.exports = g;
```

Short file, only one module exported. I don't understand how anything in that file can be responsible, and it seems to me that it is the only file mentioned in the error msg.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue in my own project by running `npm run start` from the Windows command prompt instead of Cygwin.